# jQuery FullCalendar sample insert/delete events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Anyone have an example for read/write events from calendar and json data ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is documented well on the project's homepage, also you can find a running demo for your task there

- http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/json.html

Comment: I'm sorry I'll read better faqs ;)

Comment: Domi, congrats on getting the Unsung Hero badge. :)